# Return html response to calling function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, requestify

I've got this Node.js snippet.

```
var requestify = require('requestify');
// [...]
function remoterequest(url, data) {
  requestify.post(url, data).then(function(response) {
    var res = response.getBody();
    // TODO use res to send back to the client the number of expected outputs
  });
  return true;
}
```

I need to return `res` content instead of `true`, back to the caller.

How can I do that?
In this case, the `requestify`'s method is asyncronous, therefore, the returned value is not possible to be retrieved (since it's not generated yet).
How can I solve it? How can I send a synchronous HTTP POST request (even without `requestify`)?

Comment: Can you make the function `remoterequest` async (i.e. return a promise) ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1

Comment: According to the doc, `requestify` already returns a promise: "Requestify is extremely easy to use and always return a promise"

https://github.com/ranm8/requestify

Comment: So just move the return statement to `requestify.post` line i.e. `return requestify.post(url, data).then(function(response) {`

Comment: how do you call this functoin ?

Comment: Isn't there a synchronous way to do that? Even by leaving `requestify`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return a promise and use it in the then method of the promised returned by remoteRequest :

```
var requestify = require('requestify');
// [...]
function remoterequest(url, data) {
  return requestify
    .post(url, data)
    .then((response) => response.getBody());
}

//....

remoteRequest('/foo', {bar: 'baz'}).then(res => {
  //Do something with res...
});
```

Note that it still won't be a synchronous POST though, but you will be able to use response.getBody() when available, If this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this discussion about how to use content returned from a promise [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1)

As mentionned by @Logar, you can't use directly the content returned in your promise. You must call your method returning a promise first, and use  `.then` to make the returned content available.

*Example*:

```
    var requestify = require('requestify');
    // [...]
    // This function returns a promise, so you have to call it followed by `.then` to be able to use its returned content
    function remoterequest(url, data) {
        requestify
            .post(url, data)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.getBody();
            });
    }
    //....
    //... Some other code here
    //....

    // Make a call to your function returning the promise
    remoterequest('your-url-here', {data-to-pass-as-param})
        .then((res) => { // Calling `.then` here to access the returned content from `remoterequest` function
            // Now you can use `res` content here
        });
```